# Algorithms and Graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Show that the problem of deciding whether a graph is bipartite is in **P**?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A graph is bipartite iff it admits a vertex coloring by two colors. Pick some vertex and color it white.

Use a BFS to color the graph with alternating colors layer by layer while checking for collisions. This has a runtime of $\mathcal O(n\cdot \Delta)$, where $n$ is the number of vertices and $\Delta$ is the maximal degree.

Comment: Can I get your email to do further discussion

Comment: Why? Things which are not clear to you may be unclear to others, so why not discuss it here?

Comment: I am doing math no idea about algorithms

Comment: Then why do you ask questions about runtime of algorithms? Besides, theoretical computer science is deeply intertwined with logic and can be considered as doing mathematics. In fact there is a one to one correspondence between algorithms and constructive proofs...

Comment: @PrudiiArca Could you please clarify how you got the runtime of $\mathcal{O}(n \cdot \Delta)$? I thought runtime would be $\mathcal{O}(V + E)$?

Comment: I consider for every vertex all of its neighbors, so it should be $n\cdot\Delta$. In the worst case $\Delta$ is $n-1$ (think of a complete graph). And I did not consider the costs coming from data management (like backtracking or keeping a list of all found but yet untouched vertices or so). In fact, as in the worst case $m=\binom{n}{2} = \mathcal O(n^2) $ we find $\mathcal O(n+m) = \mathcal O(n^2) = O(n\cdot \Delta)$. The intuition behind this is that by checking for collisions I will check every edge and every vertex once, so the bounds are kind of the same.